# Angular 2 @Output with (click)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/QFB5eNQlRlXe7myrPsIs?p=preview

I know this is a stupid example but I'm just trying to get working example using (click) and @Output.

I have a counter comoponent with two buttons thats increase and decreases a number and another button that I would like to used output the current number on the parent component.

Stupid example I know but just wanted something simple to learn @Output

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

  myCount: number = 5

  newCount: number

  constructor() {

  }

  countChanges(event) {
    this.myCount = event;
  }

  handleEventClicked(data){
    this.newCount = data
  }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the `Output` decorator you need two things:

1. A property decorated with it, which is an `EventEmitter` from '@angular/core' package.
2. A method which tells the output to emit a value.

For your example with a simple click event you would do the following:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'my-example',
    ...
})
export class MyExampleComponent {
    @Output()
    public myOutput = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
    
    public handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        this.myOutput.emit(event);
    }
}
```

and in your template:

```
<div (click)="handleClick($event)">click me</div>
```

From a parent component you can bind an handler to your newly created output:

```
<my-example (myOutput)="parentHandleClick($event)"></my-example>
```

You can pass whatever data you like to your EventEmitter and later get it via `$event` in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example you just need to change `handleEventClicked`

https://plnkr.co/edit/GzEbtSg103eXVv03WSm4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**child.component.html**  file

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addCount();">add Count</button>
```

**child.component.ts** file

```
@Output() myCountEmit = new EventEmitter(); // output Emitter variable
count: Number = 0;

// emit function
addCount(){
this.count++;
myCountEmit.emit({'count': this.count , 'component' : 'child component'});
}
```

**Parent.component.html** file

```
   <app-child (myCountEmit)='clickEvent($event)'></app-child>
```

**Parent.component.ts** file

```
clickEvent(value) {
    console.log(value); // output emit result
  }
```